# If then logic for insert query column case statements in transformations

Tags: t-sql

We have transformations for our ERP/CRM integration. We can hard code the transformation or use lookup tables. Now we have to comment out one method as the table lookout is commented out below. But what we need to do is check the hard code and then if the transformation isn't found in the hard code then we need to search the lookup tables for the match. An example of one column is listed below. We need something like if not found in the hard code transformation search the tables. SQL SERVER 2008R

```
,
           --degree = PC.UCURRICULM, --transformation hard coded
           curriculum = CASE PC.UMAJOR

            WHEN 'ACM' then 'ACCT'
            WHEN 'BSBA' then 'BADM'
            WHEN 'B&TS' then 'BIBT'
            WHEN 'BICH' then 'BIOC'
            WHEN 'BIO' then 'BIOL'
            WHEN 'BIS' then 'BIS'
            WHEN 'BCOM' then 'Bu Com'
            WHEN 'BUS' then 'BUSI'
            WHEN 'CHEM' then 'CHEM'
            WHEN 'AASCM' then 'CHRM'
            WHEN 'CL&A' then 'CLDA'
            WHEN 'COM' then 'COMM'
            WHEN 'CRIM' then 'CRIM'
            WHEN 'CRMJ' then 'CRMJ'
            WHEN 'CROS' then 'CROSS'
            WHEN 'DIGC' then 'DIGCIN'
            WHEN 'MED' then 'EDUC'
            WHEN 'EDES' then 'ELED'
        END
        /*
        --Transformation lookup on tables
        ,(SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(CC.CODE_VALUE_KEY, '') FROM Bridge_test.dbo.peoplechanges pc 
                        LEFT JOIN [sis_test].[dbo].[CODE_CURRICULUM] CC ON CC.[CODE_VALUE] = PC.[UMAJOR]
        */
```

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the subquery to the `case` in an `else` clause:

```
,
           --degree = PC.UCURRICULM, --transformation hard coded
           curriculum = CASE PC.UMAJOR    
            WHEN 'ACM' then 'ACCT'
            WHEN 'BSBA' then 'BADM'
            WHEN 'B&TS' then 'BIBT'
            WHEN 'BICH' then 'BIOC'
            WHEN 'BIO' then 'BIOL'
            WHEN 'BIS' then 'BIS'
            WHEN 'BCOM' then 'Bu Com'
            WHEN 'BUS' then 'BUSI'
            WHEN 'CHEM' then 'CHEM'
            WHEN 'AASCM' then 'CHRM'
            WHEN 'CL&A' then 'CLDA'
            WHEN 'COM' then 'COMM'
            WHEN 'CRIM' then 'CRIM'
            WHEN 'CRMJ' then 'CRMJ'
            WHEN 'CROS' then 'CROSS'
            WHEN 'DIGC' then 'DIGCIN'
            WHEN 'MED' then 'EDUC'
            WHEN 'EDES' then 'ELED'
            else -- Transformation lookup on tables.
              ( SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(CC.CODE_VALUE_KEY, '') FROM Bridge_test.dbo.peoplechanges pc 
                 LEFT JOIN [sis_test].[dbo].[CODE_CURRICULUM] CC ON CC.[CODE_VALUE] = PC.[UMAJOR] )
            end
```

Tip: It's good practice to include an `else` clause in general. Even if it returns `null` it shows that you made a conscious decision about how to handle "other" values.

Comment: Great it works if I include one column in the sub query

Answer (score 1):

Use this (abbreviated for clarity) code:

```
coalesce(
    case PC.UMAJOR when ... end, -- case returns null if no hit
    (SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(CC.CODE_VALUE_KEY, '') FROM Bridge_test.dbo.peoplechanges pc 
                    LEFT JOIN [sis_test].[dbo].[CODE_CURRICULUM] CC ON CC.[CODE_VALUE] = PC.[UMAJOR]
)
```

`coalesce()` returns the first non-null value in its parameter list. The case will return a null if there are no matches, in which case the select on the lookup table will be returned.

By using `COALESCE`, which takes any number of parameters, you can add another level of safety by providing a third value to coalesce in case the subquery returns a null (which would happen if `peoplechanges` was empty):

```
coalesce(
    case PC.UMAJOR when ... end, -- case returns null if no hit
    (SELECT TOP 1 ....),
    'some default'
)
```

Comment: Wow so you can do and an if then inside a column. That's brilliant! I used coalesce for null checking but didn't think of using it with a select. T-SQL just goes and goes.

Comment: Great it works if I include one column in the sub query

Comment: @blocks the advantage of this over putting a sub query inside the case is A) this is the standard way of handling “try something else if the first source is null” and B) you can add other attempts after the query in case the query returns null, eg a constant value as a fallback default

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Create a `mapperTable` table instead of HardCode `CASE WHEN`, let the code more cleaner.

in future, you just need to maintain the mapperTable.

```
CREATE TABLE mapperTalbe(
   UMAJOR varchar(50),
   curriculum varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('ACM' , 'ACCT');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('BSBA' , 'BADM');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('B&TS' , 'BIBT');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('BICH' , 'BIOC');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('BIO' , 'BIOL');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('BIS' , 'BIS');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('BCOM' , 'Bu Com');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('BUS' , 'BUSI');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('CHEM' , 'CHEM');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('AASCM' , 'CHRM');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('CL&A' , 'CLDA');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('COM' , 'COMM');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('CRIM' , 'CRIM');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('CRMJ' , 'CRMJ');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('CROS' , 'CROSS');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('DIGC' , 'DIGCIN');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('MED' , 'EDUC');
INSERT INTO mapperTalbe VALUES ('EDES' , 'ELED');

CREATE TABLE T (UMAJOR varchar(50));

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('EDES');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('CRIM');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('CRIM1');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t2.UMAJOR
FROM T t1
LEFT JOIN mapperTalbe t2 on t1.UMAJOR = t2.UMAJOR
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2191e/4/0)**:

```
| UMAJOR |
|--------|
|   CRIM |
|   EDES |
| (null) |
```

Comment: That's a neat idea. But it's a bible school and most of the users are part time and/or volunteers and there's no one to maintain any mapper tables. They won't commit to maintaining the lookup tables. So, that's why I need to look in both the code and tables.